# What model to use for relative comparison between 3 figures?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, embedding

I am working on a problem where I am given three images of different dishes `(A,B,C)` and the task is to figure out if figure `B` or figure `C` is closest to figure `A` (in terms of taste). I have a training set with ordered images `(A,P,N)` where `P` (positive) is closest to `A` (anchor) and `N` (negative). Now I figured that I somehow need to come up with an embedding that is representative of the taste, and then use a metric `d(.,.)` that meaningfully compares the dishes. Ideally `d(embedding(A),embedding(B)) < d(embedding(A),embedding(C))` implies that dish `A` is closer in taste to dish `B` than it is to dish `C`.

Now I did some research and found the so-called TripletLoss, which seems to tackle a very similar problem. A nice blog post by Olivier Moindrot can be found [here](https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss) on the topic, and it includes the figure below.

[image: https://github.com/omoindrot/tensorflow-triplet-loss]

The problem is that contrary to the implementations I found online, my dataset is not labelled. I simply have ordered triplets from which I need to extract information for the right embedding. The dishes in my dataset are all unique, and cannot be grouped meaningfully into discrete classes. Yet, I still want to come up with something like a metric that is able to compare the dishes.

My question: Am I going in the right direction? Are there any models that would suit my problem better? My knowledge of ML/NNs is still somewhat limited so any suggestion into the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Answer (score 1):

The triplet margin loss will not work in your setting, unfortunately: once you pick an anchor image, you don't have the possibility to pick the negative and the positive samples.

A possible approach off the top of my head that could allow you to work with not labelled data:

- take a pre-trained model that does food classification (e.g. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8228338)
- select one of the last layer of the model before the softmax (e.g. the last fully connected layer)
- pass your whole dataset through the pre-trained model and have a look at the embeddings of the selected layer - if the model generalizes well, the embedding should carry information on the 'taste' of the dish (up to some extent)

Another approach would be to use the triplet margin loss with labels predicted by a pre-trained model for food classification, after having passed your non-labelled dataset through the model.

Of course you could annotate your dataset, or also train a model using the triplet margin loss on an existing annotated food dataset and then test on your non-labelled datasets qualitatively.